# Get variable resizing image width and height with jquery

Tags: jquery, resize

i have a function that runs on load and window resize. I want to use the new values ​​after resizing it to another variable. I did not get the sizing part of the values​​.

```
$(window).load(function(){
           var a=imageSize();
           getResizeImageWidthHeight(a);
            otherFunction();    
        });
        $(window).resize(function(){
            imageSize();

        });
```

image resize

```
var imageSize =function() {
            var status='0';
            if( $(window).width()-300 > $(window).height() ) {
                $('#images').css({
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'height': ( $(window).height() )+'px'
                });
                status='1';
            }
            else {
                $('#images').css({
                    'width': ( $(window).width() )+'px',
                    'height': 'auto'
                });
                status='2';
            }
            return status;

        }
```

get resize image width and height

```
function getResizeImageWidthHeight(a) {
           x=a;
           if(x=='1') {
                    $("#images").load(function() {
                        imgWidth = this.width;
                        alert( "imgWidth: " + imgWidth );
                    });
                var imgHeight = $("#images").height();

            } else if(x=='2') {
                    $("#images").load(function() {
                        var imgHeight = this.height;
                    });
                var imgWidth = $("#images").width();
                alert( " imgHeight: " + imgHeight);
            } 
        }
```

and using function

```
function otherFunction() {
            var xWidth=imgWidth*2;
            var xHeight=imgHeight*3;
            .
            .
            etc. 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to scale the image with the container, there's a simpler method than re-computing the width/height when the window resizes, it is part of the [fluid layout](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images) idea.

Basically, you set the images to `max-width: 100%;` and they will scale with the size of their container.

Not sure if this is your intention, but it's less js. Check the link for more details.

**To get the sizes of the images after they are resized:**

You can save the sizes in a global variable, just remove the `var`: (not recommended)

```
imgHeight = $("#images").height();
imgWidth = $("#images").width();
```

Or you can simply query the height of the element again using jquery:

```
var xWidth = $("#images").width() * 2;
var xHeight = $("#images").height() * 3;
```

Comment: if screen resizing, image sizes that will automatically. Screen can also be a large and small. I just get the picture-scaled values​​, and the next I want to use another function. i get next-scaled the image values. Thanks Zachary.